# Cannot push file because I logged as Google Sign in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I dont know exacly how to write a title about this issue, here is the problem:

I created my account with the google plus option sign, and now I need to do a push to the remote repository, but I cannot because credentials manager asks for my credentials, and I dont have one. I tried to set a password in my bitbucket account, but I dont have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with the Google+ SignIn, you may have to use an email address and a password to create an Atlassian account.

Try to [connect to it](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQhbHijP3TAhXMjSwKHbgDDA8QjBAITjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.atlassian.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNE4ZMn4MTPn6OItR0ync_U9Rpqx3A&sig2=jh5DztgQOuFgST0g79ABIQ) and you will be able to push your files on dist repository.